# Can't reach a specific IP address in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ip

As title says, I'm trying to connect to a server, but can't. Even if I just ping it, it doesn't work. Then I turned Wireshark on to look what packages go in/out, and saw nothing go out if I try to ping via cmd. It also works fine from another machine, it's just that one address under Windows XP.
So it's most likely not my router and the server is definitely up and running.

I tried turning off the firewall, changing my IP, even disabling antivirus etc. already, still no ping request is going out, no matter what.

Does anybody here have a clue what it could be? I'm seriously confused.

Comment: What is the exact error returned by `ping` ? What is the output of `route print` ?

Comment: Are you pinging it by IP or domain name? Is it in the same LAN?

Comment: Is wireshark picking up other traffic on the interface? Does a ping to a working server display in wireshark?

Comment: What's a `tracert` show?

Comment: Im pinging a domain name, but it gets resolved fine. It simply says timeout. Wireshark doesnt show anything if i ping that, put its fine if i try it with other adresses. Tracert also timeouts.

Comment: On the destination computer is the gateway configured properly?

Comment: I guess it is, because it works fine from other PC's. I think it's on my side, because its not that i don't get a answer from the server, but cant even send a request. Atleast wireshark doesnt show anything. so its like some program blocks me from sending any packets to that specific IP. Buts its neither my firewall(I only use the normal Windows Firewall, turning it off changes nothing), nor my antivirus, nor anything that i can find myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem(some time ago already, but just thought i might post it here). Hamachi secretly grabs EVERY PACKAGE going out to a IP adress starting with 5 (5.xxx.xxx.xxx), as long as the Hamachi network connection is active.

Comment: ... which show that you should've put the failing IP or domain name in your original question. Other readers would have picked up this answer immediately from the 5.xx  IP.